# Install Drywall Authentication

Tags: git, cmd.exe, visual-studio-2010, node.js

```
C:\Users\zach\drywall>npm install

> bcrypt@0.8.5 install C:\Users\zach\drywall\node_modules\bcrypt
> node-gyp rebuild

C:\Users\zach\drywall\node_modules\bcrypt>if not defined npm_config_node_gyp (node "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )  else (node  rebuild )
Building the projects in this solution one at a time. To enable parallel build, please add the "/m" switch.
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V140\Microsoft.CppBuild.targets(366,5): warning MSB8003: Could not find WindowsSDKDir variable from the registry.  TargetFrameworkVersion or PlatformToolset may be set to an
 invalid version number. [C:\Users\zach\drywall\node_modules\bcrypt\build\bcrypt_lib.vcxproj]
TRACKER : error TRK0005: Failed to locate: "CL.exe". The system cannot find the file specified. [C:\Users\zach\drywall\node_modules\bcrypt\build\bcrypt_lib.vcxproj]


gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `msbuild` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:270:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:172:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:200:12)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.10240
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\zach\drywall\node_modules\bcrypt
gyp ERR! node -v v4.1.1
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.0.3
gyp ERR! not ok
npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.10240
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install"
npm ERR! node v4.1.1
npm ERR! npm  v2.14.4
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npm ERR! bcrypt@0.8.5 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the bcrypt@0.8.5 install script 'node-gyp rebuild'.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the bcrypt package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node-gyp rebuild
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls bcrypt
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\zach\drywall\npm-debug.log
```

I am trying to install Drywall and I was getting an error about needing visual studio 2005, so I reinstalled it but it still didn't work. So I looked around and many people solved the problem by using Visual Studio commannd line, so I tried that and now I get this error. I have no idea what it means. I was wondering if anyone knew what this means, or how to solve it. Also what is CL.exe?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Some [details on cl.exe from MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9s7c9wdw(v=vs.100).aspx):

> cl.exe is a tool that controls the Microsoft C and C++ compilers and
>   linker. cl.exe can be run only on operating systems that support
>   Microsoft Visual Studio.

Likely it cannot find cl.exe because it doesn't know which SDK directory to find it in. This is related to the previous error you receive.

> Could not find WindowsSDKDir variable from the registry. 
>   TargetFrameworkVersion or PlatformToolset may be set to an invalid
>   version number.

The WindowsSDKDir variable defines where to find different compilation tools (including cl.exe). Either you don't have the SDK installed or your environment isn't configured properly.

Try to run the setenv first before your rebuild. ([Related Link](https://gist.github.com/kosmobot/6020327))

```
call "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1\bin\Setenv.cmd" /Release /x86
```

OR

```
call "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1\bin\Setenv.cmd" /Release /x64
```

If you're still running into problems provide some more information in your question about which SDK version you have installed.

Comment: Sorry for the late response, I downloaded Visual Studio 2013 and I also downloaded Microsoft Visual Studio 2013 SDK from here: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40758. I am still getting an error. I ran both commands but they didn't find anything. Is there a way I can manually tell my computer where Cl.exe is?

Comment: Did you try running the setenv.cmd? This should configure the paths needed.

Comment: I'm not sure i'm doing it correctly, but what I did was i started my command line, i've tried it with node, git, visual studio cmd, and the default one that came on my computer, then i ran the comand call "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1\bin\Setenv.cmd" /Release /x64 and after that it would tell me "The system could not find the path specified". I looked for the directory and my Microsoft SDK's is not in program files, it is in program files (x86) also, i don't have v7.1 i have many others such as 7.0A and 7.1A. Lastly, I searched setenv.exe on my computer and it didn't find it.