# error: Command cl.exe failed: No such file or directory

Tags: windows, windows-8, windows-8.1, python, flask

The above command shows up whenever I try to install the following -

```
pip install flask-mysqldb
pip install mysqlclient
```

Comment: This may help https://superuser.com/a/1420157/726810

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the visual studio c++ build tools. These can be download separately from this page:

https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/

Navigate down to the "Tools for Visual Studio..." and select "Build Tools for Visual Studio.."

Make sure cl.exe is in your path.